# Action Bar Back Button is not showing in Android

Tags: android, android-actionbar

Hi I have created an activity which extends `ActionBarActivity` & using material theme in my application. In the Action Bar, Back button is not showing.

I didn't find why it is not showing. Any help ?

```
public class RegistrationActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_registration);

        getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ab_background_light));
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

style.xml

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <!--Support Library compatibility-->
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyTheme.ActionBarStyle</item>
</style>

<!-- ActionBar styles -->
<style name="MyTheme.ActionBarStyle" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar">
    <!--Support Library compatibility-->
    <item name="titleTextStyle">@style/MyTheme.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="MyTheme.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle" parent="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/white</item>
</style>
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
    <activity
        android:name=".RegistrationActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_registration" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".HomeScreenActivity" />
    </activity>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use `Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar` if you want icons/text to appear in white in the action bar.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

add the property

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

to show the "back button"

Answer (score 8):

If the Jorgesys's solution not worked for you. Try overriding the `onOptionsItemSelected` method.

```
public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.my_activity);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
    {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == android.R.id.home)
        {
            onBackPressed();
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

there might be a problem with your toolbar theme:

```
app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
```